# Locked questions without RSS feed still refer to it in the HTML

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed, locked-questions

Locked questions seem to have no Atom/RSS feed (which makes sense, I guess), but still refer to it in the HTML source. Hardly an issue for humans, I assume, but maybe it has some other effects.

For example: [jQuery Tips and Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks) either has both the little icon <sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub> and the feed itself missing, or its HTML should not refer to [the non-existing feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/182630), like it still does:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" 
  title="Feed for question 'jQuery Tips and Tricks'" 
  href="/feeds/question/182630">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll hide that `<link>` in the header the same as we do in the footer (for locked, deleted, and closed questions) in the next build, thanks for the catch.